# How to get current user from ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Usually while working with Spring Boot, a common way to get currently logged users is to use:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
```

This does not work when working with reactive programming, and Mono in Java since they do not belong to the same thread. It's recommended to use:

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

I've read many articles, StackOverflow questions, and answers, but never found a full explanation or example of how to fully integrate ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is what I have tried:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/get-auth", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Mono<Authentication> test(Authentication authp) {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication).doOnNext(auth -> {
        log.info("print auth", String.valueOf(auth));
    }).doOnSuccess(auth -> {
        log.error("print auth", auth);
    });
}
```

doOnSuccess - returns null
doOnNext - not triggered

Answer (score 4):

Assuming security is configured correctly. Spring security initialize `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` during subscription so you can access it within this chain using `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()`:

```java
@GetMapping
Mono<Void> getItems() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .doOnNext(auth -> log.info(String.valueOf(auth)))
            .then();
}
```

Sample output:

> UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
> [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
> [Username=admin, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true,
> AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true,
> AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]],
> Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted
> Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]

Comment: Can you give more context on "Assuming security is configured correctly", is there something that needs to be configured specifically, or the configuration might be the same as for SecurityContextHolder? Any example, steps etc..?

Comment: I have updated my question with examples, please check. It seems that I'm missing something in the configuration. That's why I said that there is no clear guide on full integration.

Comment: It would help if you could show your configuration.

Comment: Can you provide any guide/example where it's done properly? What steps are needed etc? I did not configure anything related to ReactiveSecurityContextHolder additionally. 

I have configured SecurityContextHolder in OncePerRequestFilter 

 PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken ptk = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, "n/a",
                            user.getRoles().getAuthorities());
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(ptk);

Comment: I tried, ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication). returns null.  What else i need to configure?

Comment: @TariqN dpo you have the answer?

Comment: Which line makes subscruption here ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
```

and check the response. If no authentication is returned we need to see your full SecurityWebFilterChain setup